# Expose Sitecore Data using Data Exchange Framework

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I am using Sitecore 9.3 and i am new to Sitecore Data exchange, i need to know if there is a way to expose sitecore data to third party using sitecore data exchange?

After reading about this topic, i found that i have to install tenant service package, but is there any samples for using this approach, any advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Data Exchange Framework` (DEF) pretty matches your requirements. Basically, DEF is a base that you extend with providers. There are a list provides that Sitecore provides along with DEF such as Dynamics CRM Connector, Salesforce Connector, Sitecore Forms provider etc. Also you can implement your own provider to read data from any source you want (even your custom CRM system that nobody haired about). Each provider can work in both ways: read and write. DEF just help you to communicate between providers.

For example, you can read data from `Dynamics CRM` (using Dynamics CRM Connector) and write them to `Salesforce` (using Salesforce Connector) and vice versa. Both of them are third party.

In your case, if you are going to push data from Sitecore to third party, you need to use Sitecore provider (which reads/writes items) and install/implement provender for your third party.

DEF itself is used just for run import. OOTB you can run import manually or by some schedule.

If you want to trigger import outside, you need to install TenantService or write some lines of code to run it programmatically, this code are exists in [Github](https://github.com/ampach/PipelineRunner)

Also, I tried to explain some DEF basic things on meetup: [Data Exchange Framework. How it works](https://youtu.be/fnJbrTfs3Es?t=7658)

Comment: Do you have any samples for pushing data to sitecore using Tenant service?

Comment: Hi @NAli I created a Reddit to Sitecore import with DEF so people can use it for an example. Whatever your tenant is you just need to use what you need to get the data and set the mapping. The nice thing about DEF it creates the items for you. You can check out more about DEF on my blog. Let me know if you have any questions. https://sitecorerunner.com/category/data-exchange-framework/

Comment: Thanks a lot @RReilley , its really helpful , just i have a question if the third party will need to push data to sitecore based on specific action from their side in this case i can use tenant service, right?

Comment: Sorry just saw this. @NAli yes you should be able to use an API that hooks into a tenant. In my case I had the DEF import process use a library that accessed Reddit directly and got the data it needed.

Answer (score 0):

The key word used by OP is expose. DEF will copy the data from Salesforce, Dynamics etc to Sitecore, and THEN you can expose. But it will not be realtime which sounds like maybe what you want?

I think this is what Artsem talking about when he says DEF is just for run import.

If you are happy with copy to Sitecore, be careful with your filter as DEF OOTB will do a sync which could be very very large dataset. Need to tie this down carefully cannot express this enough.

If you are not happy with copy then you need more of a connector product such as S4S (for Salesforce) or I am not sure as much what conector for Dynamics.
HTH